как расположить файл за пределами главной директории php ооп
Подскажите пожалуйста возможно ли расположить файл за пределами главной директории php?
У меня есть файл с классом для примера путь будет t2.php
<?php
class Test {
 ...
}
?>

в другом файле t1.php что бы обратится к классу расположенному в t2.php я использую оператор use. Пока оба файла находятся в пределах главной директории всё работает хорошо и мне не понять как правильно вынести файл с классом что бы всё работало хорошо и правильно.
Пробовал dirname(__DIR__, 1) прописать в use не помогло =(
Есть какие то решения данной задачи?

Чтобы использовать один класс в другом, то его надо подключить не через use, а через require или include. Т.е. в начале файла с классом Test Надо прописать include файла с другим классом. И вот уже в include можно прописать пути вне текущей директории, например include __DIR__ . './../../SomeFile.php'
Однако этот способ при работе с множеством классов и ООП неэффективен, т.к. потребуется миллион всяких include. Для автозагрузки классов рекомендую ознакомиться с автозагрузкой классов у PHP: spl_autoload_register. Но там  придётся прописать небольшую логику для их загрузки. И не забывать применять в файлах namespace, use и распологать классы структурно корректно.
Также можно использовать для автозагрузки файлов composer. Рекомендую ознакомиться что это такое и, в частности, с composer-autoload (https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload)
В его конфиге можно будет определить в какой папке будут находиться все классы, например так:
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": { "app\\": "src/" }
    }
}

Теперь надо будет лишь соблюдать правильную иерархию папок при разработки и не забывать указывать этот namespace в классах (https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.namespaces.definition.php)  ну и потом использовать use соответственно
Например если один класс находится в /src/user/hello.php, то его namespace будет например namespace app\user;,  и подключение его в другом классе будет как use app\user;

Не нужно тащить целый композер для примитивной автозагрузки. Надо открыть для себя spl_autoload_register() и научиться ей пользоваться. Это будет в сто раз полезнее, чем механически добавлять в свой код очередные заклинания, не понимая в них ни одного слова.

@Ипатьев да, как раз добавил это секунду назад

Что касается spl_autoload_register() я его использую. В любом случае спасибо именно вам Ипатьев и Дима К. за то что пнули в нужном направлении и помогли мне не наделать больших ошибок... так как про spl_autoload_register как то я не много и забыл что это главное определяющее просто после создания index-ного файла я в него больше не разу и не заглядывал и самое главное уберегли меня от composer... не знаю почему ну не лежит у меня к нему душа. Ещё раз спасибо вам пошел "творить" дальше

@Mister_X лучше потихоньку смотреть на композер. Он супер лёгкий на самом деле. И наверняка вы потом будете работать с библиотеками других разрабов и тут просто придётся ставить композер чтоб загрузить сторонние библиотеки.И тогда придётся из spl и своё вытаскивать, чтобы не было миллион автозагрузчиков в разных местах. К тому же композер очень гибкий и можно прописать разные пути и namespace для использования без необходимости писать самому бесконечный код для этого. В общем, композер - это неизбежно) Но если почитать о нём лучше - станет понятно что это супер инструмент, а spl_autolad - стар

@ДимаК. спасибо за информацию. Сайт который я сейчас делаю... делаю для себя и не планировал сторонние библиотеки. Мне нужен простой сайт. Что касается моего вопроса выше... мне стало интересно как на ооп можно вынести за пределы главной директории. Оказалось не так и сложно... в данном вопросе больше была моя не внимательность и мой склероз ... как выше уже сказал один раз index.php написал закрыл и забыл о нём, а работать в первую очередь надо было именно с ним =)
